# É possível obter o valor do atributo background-image através do xpath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, php-domxpath

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="xGh" style="background-image: url('name_file.jpg');"></div>
```

Onde preciso capturar:

`name_file.jpg`

Tentei usar a solução apresentada nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992013/get-background-image-url-using-xpath#answer-28992104), mas não está funcionado, apresenta um erro de sintaxe:

Veja o teste com o erro no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NoSAAE)

```
$img = $xpath->query(substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='xGh']/@style, "background-image: url('"), "')"));    

echo $img->item($i)->nodeValue."<br/>";
```

Sei como fazer com `regex`, mas queria utilizar `xpath`, é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível. O caminho do código esta correto, é necessário apenas corrigir a syntaxe e o xpath.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div class="xGh" style="background-image: url(\'name_file.jpg\');"></div>');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpatyQ = "substring-before(substring-after(//*[@class=\"xGh\"]/@style, \"background-image: url('\"), \"')\")";
$img = $xpath->query($xpatyQ);

$result = $xpath->evaluate($xpatyQ);
echo $result; // name_file.jpg
```

Código: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8b25d86eb97b9d59fe6155618acbc78565d2470

Comment: Veja se pode me ajudar man https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251666/como-iterar-para-obter-todos-resultados-de-xpath-evaluate  não sei ao certo se é correto solicitar ajuda dessa forma...qq fala que eu excluo...vlw:)